# Ajax jquery post is posting without a variable name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a very simple jquery ajax post function:

```
function verifyEmail(form){
    $.post('login.php',
    { 
        'email': $("#email").val()
    });
}
```

but when I call this function the request is sent but without variable name with is just as a content email="name@gmail.com" so the var_dump result is blank.

I tried changing it to a $.ajax request but the result is the same.

Comment: check the network tab if `email` is there in the form data. and also check if you have referenced a correct key name at the backend like `$_POST['email']`.

Comment: There is no any errors in your code (at least, in the part you submitted). Make sure that you have an input with the id of email. If it's not a real input field (contenteditable div?), then .val() doesn't work, use .text() instead. Also, make sure that your tag has a name attribute, and this is the same on server side too (in $_POST or $_REQUEST).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
console.log($("#email").val());
```

for seeing what value the email field have.

What kind of formfield is #email?

If there is a value in #email try

```
$.ajax({
  url: "login.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { email : $("#email").val() }
});
```

Comment: the result of the console.log is what I was expecting (name@domain.com) and the result of  the ajax request is still the same....

Comment: how do you use the var_dump?
maybe register_globals is off and you are using $email instead of $_POST['email'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
$.ajax({
 type : 'post',
 url : 'your url to send data',
 data : 'email='+$("#email").val(),
 success : function(data){
    // here you can populate data

 }
});
```

Comment: Same result the data is passed not as email as a variable and the content of the id email as the content but just as the content of an unnamed variable as email=*email id value*

Comment: As @PageconErb said, did your try to console.log($("#email").val()).